# How do I get rid of these huge black holes that are getting randomly generated in my minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just went on to my minecraft world and in the middle of a underwater structure that I had built with no issues yesterday was a huge hole. I can't place block or even go into it. Several of these appeared and they even started to occur on land. Also I have the Mo' Creatures mod and alot of the rays and dolphins are spawning around these areas.

[image]/EbQF7.jpg

[image]

Comment: Try reloading the world. That usually fixes this type of thing.

Comment: It should improve soon, according to [TheMogMiner](https://twitter.com/TheMogMiner/status/458925415579811840)

Comment: It look like the chunks weren't even generated, can you fall into them?

Answer (score 7):

Log out and then log back in again. This act of reloading the world should cause the client to regenerate the area.

What you are experiencing are '[Chunk Errors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunks#Chunk_error)'. The world hasn't loaded that particular area properly.

Comment: ive tried that several times but every time i go back into it the same chuncks are missing and some times more

Comment: @ShadowJonarcLandex Ok, are you plying on a server, or is this single player? And are you using any mods?

Comment: single player and i have 13 mods

Comment: @ShadowJonarcLandex okay, can you go through and disable them all. Then add them back one by one, testing your game each time to see if your problem is being caused by mods?

Comment: Yeah that might be an issue as one of my mods if i take it off when i go into the world it spawns huge chuncks of stone where anything from that mod was and it covers quite a lot of my area that i play in

Comment: @ShadowJonarcLandex what mods are you using?

Comment: Millenaire, Planetoid, Laser, Mo' Creatures, Golem World, Iron Man Armours, Mutant Creatures, Torch Levers,

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to force reload the missing chunks, it doesn't always work in my experience though.

Comment: thats not working either is there anything else i can do

Answer (score 0):

Shorten your field of view.  Or at the very least, cycle through them once.

Changing your field of view forces the chunks around you to reload, and using a shorter field of view means having fewer chunks you need to load, which can drastically reduce the hole-in-the-world syndrome you're experiencing.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working either

Comment: @ShadowJonarcLandex Try lowering the view to minimum and playing without a few of the mods.  The reason lower field of view helps is because large voided chunks can occur when there's too many processes going on in the game at once, and reducing the amount of land that needs to be drawn helps.  De-activating some mods should have the same effect.  Though if you know processing isn't an issue, this probably isn't the solution you're looking for.